# Assign shortcut to higligting colours in Preview

Tags: preview

Is there a way to assign some shortcut to the colours in the higlight section of Preview, e.g
CMD+1 -> highlight the selected text in Yellow
CMD+2 -> highlight the selected text in Green
...

[image]

Comment: @user3439894 thanks for the update!

Comment: I've updated the answer again, this time the new _script_ works on a normal _window_, **Full Screen View** _window_ and single/multiple display/monitor scenarios. No need to ascertain the other info in the previous version of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, not directly, as they do not exist in the normal *menu system* of the *application*.**

However, one could use .e.g., some **AppleScript** *code* in a **Run AppleScript** *action* of an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, assigned a *keyboard shortcut*, to cause the *menu button* to open as in the screen shot in your question. It would then be a matter of pressing the *key* of the first letter of the *color*, or other *menu* entry, and then the **enter** *key*.

So adding a *keyboard shortcut* to the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, e.g., **⌃⌘C**, then to change to e.g., **Blue**, one would press, e.g.,: **⌃⌘C**   **B**  **enter**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor**, and as an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, under **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

As this uses **UI Scripting** it can be *kludgy* and prone to failure for a number of different reasons. Changes to the *hierarchical **UI element**  structure*, timing issues in the *value* of a `delay` *command*, etc. However, when it works, it works!

1. In **Automator** create a new *Quick Action* with settings as shown in the image below.
2. Add a **Run AppleScript** *action* replacing the default *code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code* show below.
3. Save it as, e.g.,: **Change Highlight Color**
4. Then in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** assign it a *keyboard shortcut* of, e.g.,: **⌃⌘C**
5. Next trigged the *Service/Quick Action* manually from the **Services** *menu* in **Preview** so as to trigger the  **Security & Privacy** related dialog boxes and once that is dealt with the *keyboard shortcut* can be used freely.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Preview" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell group 2 of ¬
        toolbar 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        application process "Preview"
        try
            click menu button 1 of group 1
        on error
            try
                click menu button 1 of radio group 1
            end try
        end try
    end tell
    tell group 2 of ¬
        toolbar 1 of ¬
        group 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        application process "Preview"
        try
            click menu button 1 of group 1
        on error
            try
                click menu button 1 of radio group 1
            end try
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

**Notes:**

I have edited out the original answer, and an update, to replace all of it with a **KISS** *version* of the *script*. (One can review the edit history if one wants.)

- As coded, this works on a **normal** *window*, **Full Screen View** *window* and single/multiple display/monitor scenarios.

Note that if the assigned *keyboard shortcut* is pressed and either a *window* does not exist or the **Toolbar** is set to be hidden the *script* silently errors out, otherwise it attempts to make the *menu* show. By coding it this way and adding the additional `try` *statements*, it negates the need to ascertain whether the *window* is a **normal** *window*, **Full Screen View** *window* and using single/multiple display/monitor.

As this *script* uses **UI Scripting** and the *hierarchical **UI element** structure* changes between **Preview** being first opened, and the target *menu* having been first *clicked* and is different in a **normal** *window* vs. a **Full Screen View** *window*, this is why it's written using `try` *statements*. It allows for one of the four possible  *hierarchical **UI element** structures* to be acted upon and done so without causing an error that would stop the process otherwise.

Assuming the necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed and the **Toolbar** is available, not set to be hidden, this script should work as is until the *hierarchical **UI element** structure* changes in updates/upgrades to **macOS**. If one needs to troubleshoot the *script* not working, then run the *script* in **Script Editor** where one can examine it with the **Log** *pane* showing when run. Note that the, e.g., `delay 0.5` *command* will need to be added between the first and second lines of *code* when testing in **Script Editor**.

The *keyboard shortcut*, e.g., **⌃⌘C** is just an example because it was not already assigned elsewhere in **Preview** and can be set to whatever one likes that is not already assigned. (I actually have mine set to **⇧⌘H** from a previous answer on a different site and didn't realize it when posting this answer originally.)

Note that once the *menu* shows, one can also use the **up/down arrow** *keys* to navigate the *menu* and or press the **esc** *key* to dismiss it without making a change.

[image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>